# javascript pass control names as function parameters

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, function

I am trying to pass some control IDs from code behind to html but I do not know the control names in advance as they are created dynamically and hence I cannot use something like this: `MyTextBox = document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>");`

How can I make the following code work (if it is possible that is):

```
            TextBox test = ((TextBox)e.Row.Cells[7].Controls[0]);
            test.ID = "TextBox1";
            TextBox test2 = ((TextBox)e.Row.Cells[8].Controls[0]);
            test2.ID = "TextBox2";
            test.Attributes.Add("onChange", "javascript:MyFunc(TextBox1, TextBox2);");
```

JS function:

```
function MyFunc(TextBox1,TextBox2) {
            MyTextBox = document.getElementById("TextBox1");
            MyTextBox2 = document.getElementById("TextBox2");

            var splitDate = MyTextBox.value.split('/');
            var date = new Date(splitDate[2], splitDate[1] - 1, splitDate[0]);

            var day = date.getDate();
            var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
            var year = date.getFullYear() + 1;
            if (day < 10) {
                day = '0' + day;
            }
            if (month < 10) {
                month = '0' + month;
            }

            MyTextBox2.value = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the ids are variables, you should not enclose it with `""`

```
var MyTextBox = document.getElementById(TextBox1);
var MyTextBox2 = document.getElementById(TextBox2);
```

Also you need to change

```
test.Attributes.Add("onChange", "javascript:MyFunc('TextBox1', 'TextBox2');");
```

because both `TextBox1` and `TextBox2` has to be passed as strings

Comment: I have tried that just now and it seems that it still does not recognize TextBox1. I get this: `0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: can you add a `alert(TextBox1)` at beginning of the function and see what is alerted

Comment: It shows TextBox1 and then it breaks at: `var splitDate = MyTextBox.value.split('/');` The textboxes are created dynamically when a user clicks edit in a gridview row and the code behind gets called from the RowDataBound function of the gridview

Comment: can you inspect your dom and see whether the id of the element is set properly

Comment: I have fixed it with this: `test.Attributes.Add("onChange", "javascript:MyFunc(this, + TextBox2.ClientID + ");");` and getting rid of these lines: `MyTextBox = document.getElementById("TextBox1");
            MyTextBox2 = document.getElementById("TextBox2");
`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this,

```
 TextBox test = ((TextBox)e.Row.Cells[7].Controls[0]);
            test.ID = "TextBox1";
            test.Attributes.Add('class','TextBox1');
            TextBox test2 = ((TextBox)e.Row.Cells[8].Controls[0]);
            test2.ID = "TextBox2";
            test.Attributes.Add('class','TextBox2');
            test.Attributes.Add("onChange", "javascript:MyFunc(TextBox1, TextBox2);");
```

in JS:

```
function MyFunc(TextBox1,TextBox2) {
            MyTextBox = document.getElementByClass("TextBox1");
            MyTextBox2 = document.getElementByClass("TextBox2");

            var splitDate = MyTextBox.value.split('/');
            var date = new Date(splitDate[2], splitDate[1] - 1, splitDate[0]);

            var day = date.getDate();
            var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
            var year = date.getFullYear() + 1;
            if (day < 10) {
                day = '0' + day;
            }
            if (month < 10) {
                month = '0' + month;
            }

            MyTextBox2.value = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
        }
```

Comment: With this I get: `0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'TextBox1' is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```
test.Attributes.Add("onChange", "javascript:MyFunc(" + TextBox1.ClientID + ", " + TextBox2.ClientID + ")");
```

try this if it help.

Comment: If I do it like this: `test.Attributes.Add("onchange", "javascript:MyFunc(this, 'TextBox2');");` I can get the actual value of TextBox1 to work ok but TextBox2 still says undefined

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my answer the second one should be TextBox2